# Symfony, Doctrine and createNativeQuery

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

I started playing with Symfony and I'm trying to create a database query. As i understand it, I should use entitymanager to create a nativequery. When I do the code below, I get this warning.

> Warning: Undefined variable $entityManager

I understand that it's logical since the variable isn't initialized anywhere, but where do I get the entitymanager from?

Here is my class:

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\News;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

class NewsRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, News::class);
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
            
        $query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery('SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `id`=? LIMIT 1', $rsm);
        $query->setParameter(1, $id);
        
        $users = $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to define variable (i.e. in constructor `$this->entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();`) then [in other methods] to use it as `$this->entityManager`.

Comment: Dont hesitate to validate or/and upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in an entity repository, `_em` should be public.

You could either do:

```
public function getById($id)
{
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
        
    $query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `id`=? LIMIT 1', $rsm);
    $query->setParameter(1, $id);
    
    $users = $query->getResult();
}
```

or use autowiring to get the entity manager.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        parent::__construct($registry, News::class);
    }
```